# Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application") creates new word process even if word is already running

Tags: excel, vba

In fact even, when I have my word opened, I can't check any of opened already documents, cause `GetObject` always creates new word process each time and it has 0 opened documents.

```
    Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    wordApp.Visible = True
    Debug.Print "wordApp.Documents.Count: " & wordApp.Documents.Count  \\ returns 0
```

I've tried also getting the object like `GetObject(, "Word.Application.16")` but effect is the same.

I wonder if that has something to do with my environment. I use windows 11 and MS Office Proffessional Plus 2021

Comment: First check your task manager to see if there are multiple instances running that you are not aware of. Another option is to reboot and then try it without having any word application open. It should error when you try to make it visible because nothing will be found. - In short, it's probably finding another instance that you are not aware of, not creating a new one.

Comment: Your code works fine on my computer. Meaning it does not create a new instance and debug prints 1.

Comment: Are both Excel and Word installed at the same place? My work PC has both locally installed Office and remote Office. I tried to use the remote Excel to contact the local Word and that did not work. It failed at `set wordApp`. So if you have both local and remote installs make sure you use the same installs on both apps.

Comment: Seems like restart of whole computer helped. Thanks!